# Unable to use Azure Data Explorer connector in Power Bi " We reach the end of buffer message"

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to connect azure data explorer to Power BI desktop. When I try to connect it - it's throwing an error "We reached the end of the buffer."

[image]

I tried couple of workarounds, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue clearing the Power BI Cache:

- Under "**File > Options and settings > Options > Data Load > Data Cache Management Options > Clear Cache**"